# How to customise Steppers in flutter and control through widgets in content?

Tags: flutter

I created a sequence of steps in my view which I want to implement using the Stepper Widget in Flutter. However I want the steps to be triggered by widgets in the  content instead of Continue and Cancel. I tried to use controlsBuilder however that creates the same control widget for each step. In my requirement i want different widgets to trigger the flow. my first step is a yes-no question. Next Step should be controlled by whether there is an image in the view and so on. 
How do i achieve this?

Is there a way to create a custom Stepper bar and avoid the Stepper class altogether ?

This is the flow i want to achieve with stepper :

https://ibb.co/KzJYGdQ

https://ibb.co/BsHZbHd

I tried the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StepperView extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _stepperViewState createState() => _stepperViewState();
}

class _stepperViewState extends State<StepperView> {

  //bool itemBought = false;

  int _currentstep = 0;
  void _movetonext() {
    setState(() {
      if(_currentstep< steps.length-1){
        _currentstep++;
      }
    });
  }

  void _movetostart() {
    setState(() {
      _currentstep = 0;
    });
  }


  List<Step> steps = [
    Step(
      title: Text("Item bought?"),
      content: Column(
  children: <Widget> [
  Row(
  children: <Widget>[

  GestureDetector(
  //onTap: _movetonext,
    // (GIVES ERROR: only static members can accessed in initializers )
  child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 1.0), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),child: Center(
  child: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0, bottom: 6.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
  child: Text('NO', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 9.0)),
  ),
  )),
  ),
  SizedBox(width: 10.0),

  GestureDetector(
 //onTap: _movetostart,
    // (GIVES ERROR: only static members can accessed in initializers )
  child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red,border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 1.0),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),child: Center(
  child: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0, bottom: 6.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
  child: Text('YES', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 9.0)),
  ),
  )),
  ),

  ])]),
      isActive: true,
    ),

    Step(
      title: Text("Step 2"),
      content: Text("this is the second step"),
      isActive: true,
    ),
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Stepper(
      controlsBuilder:
          (BuildContext context, {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
        /*return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: onStepContinue,
              child: const Text('CONTINUE'),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: onStepCancel,
              child: const Text('CANCEL'),
            ),
          ],
        ); */
      },
      currentStep: this._currentstep,
      type: StepperType.vertical,
      steps: steps,
      onStepTapped: (step){
          setState(() {
            _currentstep = step;
          });
        },
        onStepCancel: _movetostart,
        onStepContinue: _movetonext
      ,
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While your use case seems to have an unconventional design for a Stepper, it's possible to modify the existing Stepper widget. You can just copy the existing Stepper widget class and add arguments that'll override the text set on 'Next' and 'Cancel' buttons.

Add the desired arguments on the Step class. Some lines that are unchanged are omitted for simplicity.

```dart
class CustomStep {
  /// Creates a step for a [CustomStepper].
  ///
  /// The [title], [content], and [state] arguments must not be null.
  const CustomStep({
  required this.title,
  this.subtitle,
  required this.content,
  this.state = StepState.indexed,
  this.isActive = false,
  this.continueButtonLabel, // String for 'Next' button
  this.cancelButtonLabel,   // String for 'Cancel' button
  }) : assert(title != null),
  assert(content != null),
  assert(state != null);

  ...

  /// Set a different text on Stepper Continue Button
  final String? continueButtonLabel;

  /// Set a different text on Stepper Cancel Button
  final String? cancelButtonLabel;
}
```

Then inside `_CustomStepperState` class, add an `index` parameter for `Widget _buildVerticalControls()`. Find the `TextButton` for 'Next' and 'Cancel' buttons and modify them to be able to handle the parameters that you've set.

```dart
Widget _buildVerticalControls(int index) {

  ...

  // If continueButtonLabel is empty, display default text
  Text((widget.steps[index].continueButtonLabel !=null) ? widget.steps[index].continueButtonLabel! : localizations.continueButtonLabel)
  
  ...

  // If cancelButtonLabel is empty, display default text
  Text((widget.steps[index].cancelButtonLabel !=null) ? widget.steps[index].cancelButtonLabel! : localizations.cancelButtonLabel),
}
```

Using this approach, changing the button's appearance is also possible. Here's the [complete custom_stepper.dart](https://gist.github.com/omatt/d226ddabe521aad91f2a850f89cad694) if you'd like to try it out.

On your screen, you'll just need to add the parameters `continueButtonLabel` and `cancelButtonLabel` for it to work.

```dart
int _index = 0;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: CustomStepper(
        currentStep: _index,
        onStepCancel: () {
          if (_index > 0) {
            setState(() {
               _index -= 1;
            });
          }
        },
        onStepContinue: () {
          if (_index <= 0) {
            setState(() {
              _index += 1;
            });
          }
        },
        onStepTapped: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _index = index;
          });
        },
        steps: <CustomStep>[
          CustomStep(
            title: const Text('Step 1 title'),
            content: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: const Text('Content for Step 1'),
            ),
            // Set custom label for the 'Next' button
            continueButtonLabel: 'Next',
            // Set custom label for the 'Cancel' button
            cancelButtonLabel: 'Back',
          ),
          const CustomStep(
            title: Text('Step 2 title'),
            content: Text('Content for Step 2'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: Demo]