# Customize Stepper in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to customize the Steppers in flutter.

1. How can I place the **Step title** to the left of each step bar?
2. How can I change the line bar to the **dotted bar** of the **stepper**?
3. And how can I customize the **state** of the **step** other than the 5 **StepState** provided like a round bubble?

Here is my code.

```
Container(
  child: Stepper(
    currentStep: 0,
    controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, {
      VoidCallback onStepContinue,
      VoidCallback onStepCancel
    }) => Container(),
    steps: [
      Step(
        content: Container(
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('9:00Am - 10:00AM'),
                Text(
                  'Everest Tour',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: Text('9:00 AM'),
      ),
      Step(
        content: Text('2nd Data'),
        title: Text('10:00 AM'),
        state: StepState.editing,
        isActive: true,
        subtitle: Text('subtitle')
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: The [Stepper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) widget doesn't seem to support what you want to do. You would have to create your own stepper widget.

Comment: Hi @JoãoSoares Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the Stepper widget by modifying the original Stepper widget class. Here's a [customized Stepper widget](https://gist.github.com/omatt/e2330ac782de77b817ecd038a5bd6b7c) I've created that can be configured with optional `stepIndicatorAlignment` and `dottedLine` arguments. The text on 'Continue' and 'Cancel' buttons can also be modified.

Here's a sample on how it can be implemented.

```dart
CustomStepper(
  // stepIndicatorAlignment is set to StepIndicatorAlignment.left by default if not configured
  stepIndicatorAlignment: StepIndicatorAlignment.right,
  // dottedLine is set to false by default if not configured
  dottedLine: true, 
  currentStep: _index,
  onStepCancel: () {
    if (_index > 0) {
      setState(() {
        _index -= 1;
      });
    }
  },
  onStepContinue: () {
    if (_index <= 0) {
      setState(() {
        _index += 1;
      });
    }
  },
  onStepTapped: (int index) {
    setState(() {
      _index = index;
    });
  },
  steps: <CustomStep>[
    CustomStep(
      title: const Text('Step 1 title'),
      content: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: const Text('Content for Step 1'),
      ),
      continueButtonLabel: 'YES',
      cancelButtonLabel: 'NO',
    ),
    CustomStep(
      title: Text('Step 2 title'),
      content: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text('Content for Step 2'),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image: Demo]

In this [similar Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68120787/2497859), I've explained how I'm able to modify the stock Flutter Stepper widget.